# Are snails on spider plant a problem and how to get rid of them.

Tags: snails

Today morning I noticed a pair of snails on my spider plant. They were very tiny (Almost unnoticeable). I don't want to kill them however need to know if they could cause any harm to the plant. If yes please suggest a way to get rid of them. Today I just caught them on a piece of paper and threw away.

P.S: I have some other young plants in my balcony (hibiscus, chilli, fenugreek). Do let me know if not killing them could be a danger to these plants in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what the snails are doing - if they like a particular plant, they can decimate it completely, down to the ground. They seem to particularly like young shoots on favoured plants, so if you notice leaves disappearing or being chewed, then they'll be probably be the culprits. You can either inspect regularly and remove any you see, or use something that does kill them if their population becomes excessive. They tend to hide in shady, damper spots, so under the rims of pots, behind pots, that kind of thing. I'd recommend slug pellets to kill them, if you have such a thing available.